# passing foreign key id in the next page state

Tags: reactjs, binding

I am tying to pass the value of the foreign key id in the next page state in reactjs. .This is my current state for the first page.

```
constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);


        this.state = {
            apiUrl: config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
            categoryName: " ",
            subCategoryName:" ",
            squareFeet:" ",
            leadServeyId:" ",
};
        this.saveValue = this.saveValue.bind(this);
        this.savedValue= this.savedValue.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

I am getting this value in the backend for the first page.

```
id:39ce4374-a79c-470a-b95f-befd046eb654
{'categoryName': 'Commercial', 'subCategoryName': 'Restaurant', 'squareFeet': 2371, 'leadServeyId': ' '}
```

All i want is pass this id as a foreign key in the next page,merge the value and update the state of the next page.This is second page state:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            apiUrl:config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
            FreeEstimateName :"",
            FreeEstimateEmail :"",
            FreeEstimateMobile :"",
            leadServeyId:this.props.leadParamId,
};

        this.handleFreeEstimateName = this.handleFreeEstimateName.bind(this);
        this.handleFreeEstimateEmail = this.handleFreeEstimateEmail.bind(this);
        this.handleFreeEstimateMobile= this.handleFreeEstimateMobile.bind(this);
}
```

I tried using routing like this.But its not working:

```
 handleClick = () => {
        Router.push({
            pathname: '/pagename',
            query: { leadParamId: this.props.leadServeyid },
        },{ shallow: true })
    }

static getInitialProps ({ query: { leadParamId} }) {
        console.log('getInitialProps colling ...');
        return { leadParamId: leadParamId}
    }
```

How can i  make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example on how to send parameters to another component using React Router.

You have Routes defined like these:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/create" exact render={() => <Create/> }/>
  <Route path="/my-list" exact render={() => <List users ={ users }/> }/>
  <Route path="/login" exact render={() => <Login/> }/>
  <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Home/> }/>
  <Route render={() => <Error404/> }/>
</Switch>
```

Then you have a navbar componenent with all the links to those routes:

```
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const navbar = (props) => {

    const navigateToCreate = () => {
        props.history.push('/create', { id: 7, color: 'green' });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Authentication</NavLink>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/create" exact>Create</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/my-list" exact>My List</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/login" exact>Login</NavLink>
                        **<button onClick = { navigateToCreate }></button>**
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(navbar);
```

There is a button that will navigate programmatically to **create** component by executing function navigateToCreate(). Do not forget to import withRouter object from react-router-dom in order to access all the props passed via react-router(like: history, location, params, etc..).

Alongside navigating to **create** component we are passing an object { id: 7, color: 'green' }. (Your issue: Passing properties to another component via react-router).

Final Step: Receiving the props at **create** component.

**create** component looks like this

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const create = (props) => {
    //here you access all the params sent from navbar component
    console.log(props.history.location.state);
    //result: {id: 7, color: "green"}
    return (
        <div>
            <p>CREATE</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(create);
```

> Again: In order to access all the properties provide by react-router
>   you should wrap your component with withRouter object imported from
>   'react-router-dom'.